# Fitting an exponential distribution to data and finding third quartile problem

Tags: distributions, matlab, quantiles, exponential-distribution

I have a data-set with range of `0 to 1`. I'm fitting a distribution to it in `MATLAB` using `fitdist(Data_set, 'exponential')`. I want find third quartile with `log(4)/λ` . When I calculate this, the result is `4.28738`As i mentioned my data set range is between `0 and 1`. why this value is bigger than maximum of my data range? How can i solve this problem? I think this is from tail o exponential distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a data-set with range of 0 to 1.

The exponential distribution seems not to be the right model since this distribution has support on the positive real line. This is, you are fitting a model that assigns positive probability to sets of values that are unreasonable in your context.

The most popular distributions with support on $(0,1)$ are the Beta distribution and the Kumaraswamy distribution. If you fit one of these, then you will get a quartile in the right range.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution

```
fitdist(Data_set, 'Beta')
betainv(P,A,B)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I searched for quartiles of beta distribution but i didn't find something like exponential distribution. How can I calculate quartiles using `a` and `b` parameters of beta distribution?

Comment: @user2991243 For the beta distribution the quantile function is, unfortunately, not available in closed-form. However, you can approximate it numerically using  MATLAB.

Comment: How can I run this code? I think this isn't for MATLAB ! thanks.

Comment: @user2991243 I think I just found it: it is [betainv](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/betainv.html).

Comment: Can you prepare some sample code for using it in your main answer? thanks.